# ngModelChange triggers before the model is actually changed

Tags: angular

Is there an event that triggers after a model is changed, and not before the change? Everytime a checkbox is set, I need to check whether I can enable a next button. So I loop through my list to check in any object is selected. However the values are first bound after the ModelChange event:

```
<tr *ngFor="let social of socialMediaList">
   <td>{{social.name}}</td>
   <td>
      <input type="checkbox" (ngModelChange)="onSocialMediaChange($event)" type="checkbox" name="options"
                [(ngModel)]="social.selected">
   </td>
</tr>
```

My js:

```
onSocialMediaChange($event) {
    this.ageRangeList = null;
    this.canContinueFromSocialNetwork = this.socialMediaList.filter((item) => item.selected === true).length>0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `FormsModule` to the imports of the module helped solve this issue.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure the **ngModelChange** attribute is after the **ngModel** attribute.

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  [(ngModel)]="social.selected" // 1st place
  (ngModelChange)="onSocialMediaChange($event)" // 2nd place
  name="options">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the social object as part of modelChange event. Inside component, using event you can check whether checked checked or not.

```
onSocialMediaChange(event, social){
    console.log(this.socialMediaList);
    social.selected = event;
    this.canContinueFromSocialNetwork = this.socialMediaList.filter((item) => item.selected).length>0;
    console.log(this.canContinueFromSocialNetwork);

  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pockxp

Comment: But this only tell me about the checkbox being checked, and not whether other in the array are checked. I could of course do a check on both the current checkbox and then if the array contains any selected. But not super beautiful:D

Comment: This code does check for array selected item. this.canContinueFromSocialNetwork = this.socialMediaList.filter((item) => item.selected).length>0

Comment: Are your right, you set it in the function. Thanks!

Comment: this doesn't look like binding, looks like reassignation